# Adding data to an ArrayList repeatedly

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I am trying to add 100 (realistically more) Strings to an ArrayList. Instead of adding each String individually, how can I use something like a for loop to add them at once. The code below is an example.

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList();

String s1 = "Apple";
String s2 = "Banana";
String s3 = "Pear"

/*
    More Strings created until the 100th String
    .
    .
    .

*/

String s100 = "Kiwi";

//for loop to try add each String to List
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    //Code to add each String to the arraylist
}
```

Can anyone identify the how I can add each String to the list?

Thanks much appreciated

Comment: Why use separate `String` variables? Why not just add directly to the `ArrayList`?

Comment: Well to be honest I'm not dealing with String's, I'm using objects which I create and then add them to an Arraylist of type object (which is a class I created) 
So if I know how to add Strings to the List individually, then I can apply it to the objects. Thanks

Comment: If you are trying to find a simple solution like PHP's eval function, like `$s1 = 'test'; echo eval("\$s1;");` It's not going to happen. You cant call a variable using it's name as a string.

Comment: It's hard to say unless one is sure exactly where the string data is coming from.  If they're just constants, then perhaps put them in an array and iterate over the array, adding each individually.  You could make an enum, and iterate over the enum and add them individually.  If you read them from a file, you'd read each string in and add it to the array list.  From a database, you'd fetch each record, and add it in the fetch loop.

Comment: The data is hard coded actually. In fact I have a class for the individual variables, and so far they are added individually to the list (which is annoying). There not constants too. I could use enum's, but I think that could complicate the problem. 
Thanks the reply

Answer (score 1):

From your comments you are dealing with custom objects. Regardless of how you want to transfer data from the objects into your `ArrayList`, better to use a collection. The type of the collection will depend on the source of your object data. As the data is hard-coded you could use an array. Multiple variables like these

```
String s1 = "Apple";
String s2 = "Banana";
String s3 = "Pear"
```

become

```
String[] fruitArray = {
   "Apple",
   "Banana",
   "Pear"
   ...
};
```

Then to add:

```
for (String fruit: fruitArray) {
   strings.add(fruit);
}
```

As already stated my comment above, a cleaner design would be to to use a single `List<MyObject>` to contain all objects in a [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) approach and just extract a `String` as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That seems OK, but I don't have a List (such as myObjects) with data in it. So therefore I wont be able to transfer it to another List (strings). 

Is there a way you can use an index (such as 'i') that can concatenate with 's' in the for loop? Which will then add like "s1", "s2" etc to the List (strings) 
Thanks again

Comment: Yes, and there are alot more than a 100. So it would be great to add them to a list quickly.

Comment: OK Thanks. That would be alot easier to use an array. Il see how I go. Much appreciated from your help

Comment: Yup, I agree with @Reimeus. Reflection is a cumbersome topic, if you can change your code that will be a lot easier... cheers

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could create a sophisticated strategy using reflection to fetch all variables of a given class and add them to a List; subsequently, you could loop this List and do whatever you want.

However, I do not think it would solve your problem. Indeed, you are likely to run into several pitfalls.

I would change your approach to the problem. Create a static List and add whatever you need there (or a Singleton, it depends how you want to manage this List). Once you have the list of objects you can loop it.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yea it's a pretty nifty problem. I'l look into reflections and figure it out. Thanks again

Comment: @DouglasGrealis, just a question before you start working with reflection. Are these local variables? If yes, you need to take it at runtime; so, it will give you lots of headache. If not, then you can easily take the class members via reflection.

Comment: Yes, there defined inside a method. How do you mean by taking it at runtime? In fact iv'e never used reflection anyway. Thanks

Comment: Local variables (variables inside a method) can not be fetched via reflection, they are loaded by the main thread at runtime; so, you need a thread dump to fetch these variable. It's a complex subject, I do not advise going through this way, only if you can not modify the code (like in a third part provider). You mentioned that these values are hard coded... So I would suggest: (1) Add everything in an enumeration and use getEnumConstants() or values(); (2) Add everything in List and loop it.

Comment: OK I see. Thanks for the advise. How I was going about it was, if I used an index (such as 'i') that could concatenate with say 's' inside a for loop which will then add like 's1', 's2' etc adding each String to the List. But I dont think that is possible. I'l look into enum's tho. Thanks